# Having problems implementing SAT polygon collision detection in Java

Tags: java, collision-detection, polygon, game-engine, game-physics

Im currently trying to implement SAT in java but for some reason it doesn't work. I have rewritten my code multiple times, looked over it even more and watched many tutorials but cant find my mistake. In some cases for some edges it works partly properly but otherwise it detects collision when not colliding.
Later i'll add AABB collision detection for better performance.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:

SAT class:

```
public class SAT {
    public static boolean checkSAT(Polygon poly1, Polygon poly2) {
        Vector[] axes = new Vector[poly1.p.length + poly2.p.length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < poly1.p.length + poly2.p.length; i++) {
            int a = i; if(i == poly1.p.length) a -= poly1.p.length;
            axes[i] = poly1.getEdge(a).getNormal().getNormalized();
            
        }
        
        double p1_min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, p1_max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
               p2_min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, p2_max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < axes.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < poly1.p.length; j++) {
                double proj = axes[i].dotProduct(poly1.p[j]);
                if(proj < p1_min) p1_min = proj;
                if(proj > p1_max) p1_max = proj;
                
            }
            
            for (int j = 0; j < poly2.p.length; j++) {
                double proj = axes[i].dotProduct(poly2.p[j]);
                if(proj < p2_min) p2_min = proj;
                if(proj > p2_max) p2_max = proj;
                
            }
            
            if (p1_max < p2_min || p2_max < p1_min)
                return false;
            
        }
        
        return true;
        
    }
}
```

vector class:

```
public class Vector {
    public final double x;
    public final double y;
    
    public Vector(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        
    }
    
    public Vector getNormal() {
        return new Vector(-y, x);
        
    }
    
    public double getLength() {
        return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
        
    }
    
    public Vector getNormalized() {
        double l = getLength();
        
        return new Vector(x/l, y/l);
        
    }
    
    public double dotProduct(Vector vec) {
        return x * vec.x + y * vec.y;
    }
    
}
```

relevant parts of the polygon class:

```
public class Polygon {
    public Vector[] m; //"model" of the polygon
    public Vector[] p; //coordinates of the corners of the polygon in space
    
    public double posX;
    public double posY;
    
    public Polygon(Vector[] m) {
        this.m = m;
        
        p = new Vector[m.length];
        
        transform();
        
    }
    
    //later i'll add rotation
    public void transform() {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            p[i] = new Vector(m[i].x + posX, m[i].y + posY);
        }
        
    }
    
    public void setPosition(Vector pos) {
        posX = pos.x;
        posY = pos.y;
        
        transform();
        
    }
    
    public Vector getEdge(int i) {
        if(i >= p.length) i = 0;
        int j = i+1; if(j >= p.length) j = 0;
        return new Vector(p[j].x - p[i].x, p[j].y - p[i].y);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger?  That is the 1st thing to do

Comment: No, but i'll do that next.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I found the mistake and it's just plain stupid!! And on top of that I spend more than 5 hours finding it!!!!!!

```
        double p1_min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, p1_max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 
               p2_min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, p2_max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        //those doubles should be declared inside the for loop

        for (int i = 0; i < axes.length; i++) {
            //right here

            for (int j = 0; j < poly1.p.length; j++) {
                double proj = axes[i].dotProduct(poly1.p[j]);
                if(proj < p1_min) p1_min = proj;
                if(proj > p1_max) p1_max = proj;
                
            }
            
            for (int j = 0; j < poly2.p.length; j++) {
                double proj = axes[i].dotProduct(poly2.p[j]);
                if(proj < p2_min) p2_min = proj;
                if(proj > p2_max) p2_max = proj;
                
            }
            
            if (p1_max < p2_min || p2_max < p1_min)
                return false;
            
        }
```